# JS myArray[length] returns the first element

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone walk me through what JavaScript is doing here.

```js
var myArray = ["Hello", "world"]
console.log(myArray[length])
```

We get the output as **Hello**.

Comment: I get a Syntax Error. [Mcve] please!

Comment: What output were you expecting instead?

Comment: I was expecting undefined. MyArray[2] 2 being the length of the array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length) is defined in window, which is 0 if you don't have frames.

So, `myArray[0]` is "Hello", while `myArray[1]` is "world"

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to achieve this?

```js
const myArray = ["Hello", "world"]
console.log(myArray[myArray.length - 1])
```

Comment: Not trying to achieve anything just wanted to understand from where it was picking the value of length as 0